# Odometry service or topic?

Tags: navigation, odometry, turtlebot, service, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I can get odometry using service or a topic. How can I choose between the 2 possibilities ?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235975/odometry-service-or-topic-?/) by [goupil35000](https://answers.ros.org/users/7096/goupil35000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2016-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think that you should use topics for that.

It depends on how often you receive data.

Services are useful when you want to do a specific action sometimes.

Topics are used when you often received data (data from sensors, command control to drive your robot, odometry, ...)

---

Originally posted by [F.Brosseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/22477/f.brosseau/) with karma: 379 on 2016-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2